# How to delete row in sql without deleting whole table

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to delete a row from my table which has the same headings as the column titles. e.g.

**`Number`| `Name`|`Nat`| `Pos`| `Height`| `Weight`| `Birth Place`| `Previous Club`**

`Number`| `Name`|`Nat`| `Pos`| `Height`| `Weight`| `Birth Place`| `Previous Club`

`1` | `joe blogg`| `eng`| `forward`| `1.95`| `85`| `london`| `london fc`

This query
("DELETE FROM Table `table1` WHERE `Number` = `Number`");

deletes the whole table but i just want to delete the row above the where number = 1

Comment: FWIW, `WHERE Number = Number` means delete all the rows where the value in the "Number" column is equal to the value in the "Number" column... which would be all rows where Number isn't NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Try DELETE FROM Table table1 WHERE Number = 'Number'

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
DELETE FROM Table table1
    WHERE Number = 1;
```

If you have a local variable called `Number` (say in a stored procedure or trigger), then you have a very poor name for the variable.  It conflicts with a column name.  When using such variables, I prefix them with `v_` (or something similar), so they will not be confused with column names.

Comment: yeah the naming structure got messed up when i done an Import. I don't want to delete the row with 1 ive been trying to delete the middle row.